# How to convert inner native sql to JPQL

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hql, jpql

Hi Here is my entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "COMMENTS")
public class Comment {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1606236771730211148L;

    @NotNull
    private Instant created_On; // immutable

    @Id
    @NotNull
    @Column(updatable = false)
    private String uuid;

    @NotNull
    private DomainReference domainRef; // immutable

}
```

Here is my table looks like.

```
UUID        Varchar     Unique id 
CREATED_ON  TIMESTAMP   Instant
Encounter   Varchar     encounter
```

I need a query that looks up the latest N Number of rows by each encounter. So if there are 3 encounters they each can have up to N Number rows.

Here is my native sql query

```
SELECT a.* FROM (
SELECT COMMENTS.UUID ,COMMENTS.DOMAINREF, COMMENTS.CREATED_ON
ROW_Number() OVER(PARTITION BY COMMENTS.DOMAINREF ORDER BY COMMENTS.CREATED_ON DESC) AS rn   
FROM COMMENTS WHERE COMMENTS.DOMAINREF IN ('1','2'))  a 
WHERE a.rn <= 1;
```

Here is my partially converted JPQL query.

```
 SELECT a.UUID,a.domainRef,a.CREATED_ON FROM 
 ( SELECT COMMENT.UUID,COMMENT.domainRef,COMMENT.CREATED_ON,
 ROW_Number() OVER(PARTITION BY IAW_COMMENT.domainRef ORDER BY COMMENT.CREATED_ON DESC) AS rn
 FROM COMMENT WHERE COMMENT.domainRef IN :domainrefs)  a
 WHERE a.rn <= :maxNum";
```

This query will create table called  "a" which is not my entity. I'm not sure if JPA handles inner queries and returns the matching entity. 
Can we convert this query into JPQL query?

Comment: OVER(PARTITION BY COMMENTS.DOMAINREF) is not portable to JPQL what are trying to do

Comment: Using JPA entity manager, i'm passing a list of domainRefs to the query and expecting result which will contain maximum of 10 latest rows for each element in the list.